# Video autoloading

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running a projet of video galery. My problem is I want to the use the YouTube system so that when I click on a video in the list of the galery it appears in the main space and start playing (exactly what happens in YouTube). How can I do this please ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a video to start playing automatically when pressing the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, get the youtube api and a fetch method to get the videos,

now loop through the data returned and present it in the manner you want it. write a play method that will open a selected video on a play canvas, this is how I think you can implement what you want in bare design thinking. I dont know what technologies you're using, in my free time I'll write an example implementation in vue.js or react.js